# MobileFirst Proguard returned with error code 1. See console java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I am receiving this exception while trying to create signed apk of my sample  application.

kindly guide me to resolve this problem.

I have updated latest 7.1.0.0-MFPF-StudioP2-IF201607111057 in MobileFirst 7.1.

```
[2016-07-29 13:16:13 - samAPPSampleAndroid] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console    
[2016-07-29 13:16:13 - samAPPSampleAndroid] Note: there were 2641 duplicate class definitions.
[2016-07-29 13:16:13 - samAPPSampleAndroid]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2016-07-29 13:16:13 - samAPPSampleAndroid] java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to java.lang.String
[2016-07-29 13:16:13 - samAPPSampleAndroid]     at proguard.obfuscate.MemberObfuscator.newMemberName(MemberObfuscator.java:198)
[2016-07-29 13:16:13 - samAPPSampleAndroid]     at proguard.obfuscate.MemberNameCollector.visitAnyMember(MemberNameCollector.java:74)
[2016-07-29 13:16:13 - samAPPSampleAndroid]     at proguard.classfile.util.SimplifiedVisitor.visitProgramMember(SimplifiedVisitor.java:79)
[2016-07-29 13:16:13 - samAPPSampleAndroid]     at proguard.classfile.util.SimplifiedVisitor.visitProgramMethod(SimplifiedVisitor.java:91)
[2016-07-29 13:16:13 - samAPPSampleAndroid]     at proguard.classfile.visitor.MemberAccessFilter.visitProgramMethod(MemberAccessFilter.java:90)
[2016-07-29 13:16:13 - samAPPSampleAndroid]     at proguard.classfile.ProgramMethod.accept(ProgramMethod.java:71)
[2016-07-29 13:16:13 - samAPPSampleAndroid]     at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.methodsAccept(ProgramClass.java:504)
[2016-07-29 13:16:13 - samAPPSampleAndroid]     at proguard.classfile.visitor.AllMemberVisitor.visitProgramClass(AllMemberVisitor.java:48)
[2016-07-29 13:16:13 - samAPPSampleAndroid]     at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.accept(ProgramClass.java:346)
[2016-07-29 13:16:13 - samAPPSampleAndroid]     at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.hierarchyAccept(ProgramClass.java:359)
[2016-07-29 13:16:13 - samAPPSampleAndroid]     at proguard.classfile.LibraryClass.hierarchyAccept(LibraryClass.java:371)
[2016-07-29 13:16:13 - samAPPSampleAndroid]     at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.hierarchyAccept(ProgramClass.java:416)
[2016-07-29 13:16:13 - samAPPSampleAndroid]     at proguard.classfile.visitor.ClassHierarchyTraveler.visitProgramClass(ClassHierarchyTraveler.java:75)
[2016-07-29 13:16:13 - samAPPSampleAndroid]     at proguard.classfile.visitor.MultiClassVisitor.visitProgramClass(MultiClassVisitor.java:85)
[2016-07-29 13:16:13 - samAPPSampleAndroid]     at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.accept(ProgramClass.java:346)
[2016-07-29 13:16:13 - samAPPSampleAndroid]     at proguard.classfile.ClassPool.classesAccept(ClassPool.java:116)
[2016-07-29 13:16:13 - samAPPSampleAndroid]     at proguard.obfuscate.Obfuscator.execute(Obfuscator.java:217)
[2016-07-29 13:16:13 - samAPPSampleAndroid]     at proguard.ProGuard.obfuscate(ProGuard.java:333)
[2016-07-29 13:16:13 - samAPPSampleAndroid]     at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:135)
[2016-07-29 13:16:13 - samAPPSampleAndroid]     at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

> Project.Properties

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
# 
# This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
# 
# To customize properties used by the Ant build system use,
# "build.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
# project structure.

# Indicates whether an apk should be generated for each density. split.density=false
# Project target. target=android-21

# Uncomment the line below to enable Android Proguard proguard.config=proguard-project.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Helo Krish,

First of all, pay attention to this warning. It is very important that you keep the code tidy and organized and having duplicates

```
Proguard returned with error code 1. See console    
[2016-07-29 13:16:13 - samAPPSampleAndroid] Note: there were 2641 duplicate class definitions.
[2016-07-29 13:16:13 - samAPPSampleAndroid]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
```

Regarding this error, there is a line in your project where you casting/treating an Object as a String and Proguard is simply not being able to deal with it

```
[2016-07-29 13:16:13 - samAPPSampleAndroid] java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

Check your code for any possible wrong cast and deal with it.
Also, [check this other post related to a Proguard ClassCastException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18782621/android-cast-string-with-gson-proguard)

Comment: I'm have used IBM MobileFirst V7.1 and created sample application which gives this error. i haven't added any jar or java files newly.